# A hunting lodge has enough fuel to keep 20 room heated for fourteen days

Tags: algebra-precalculus

A hunting lodge has enough fuel to keep 20 room heated for fourteen days . If the lodge decides to save fuel by turning off the heat in 5 unoccupied rooms, and each room requires the same amount of fuel to heat it, how many extra full days will the fuel supply last ?

Comment: @ronno Algebra-precalc?

Comment: is it 3 full days?

Comment: This question is from the Manhattan GRE practice book. There is a mistake in the book, though. The "correct" answer is D(18). But that's the number of days the fuel will last, NOT the number of extra days. So the number of EXTRA days is 4.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fuel is enough for 20*14 = 280 room-days. If you're heating 15 rooms, you can sustain heat for 280/15 = 18.6666... days. That's four extra FULL days.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** Let $x$ be the number of days that the lodge can supply to $15$ rooms (inversely proportional):
$$\dfrac{15}{20}=\dfrac{14}{x}$$
Thus, $x-20=\dfrac{20\times14}{15}-20$.

Comment: This is incorrect. You get x = 10.5 days. Surely if you heat fewer rooms, you can sustain it for longer, not shorter?

Comment: @Deepak I made a mistake - I meant to pot inversely proportional, but something happened... I edited my answer.

Comment: Sorry, it's still not correct. The correct equation is $\frac{x}{14} = \frac{20}{15}$

Comment: @Deepak Now?${}{}$

Comment: The equation is correct now, but you have to subtract 14, not 20. :)